# autocomplete database using while with array

Tags: php, arrays, jquery-ui, autocomplete, while-loop

I'm using [Autocomplete UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote). I have some ploblems with results of a database source, what i need its simple:

In the example from doc's, they have a array like this:

```
$items = array(
 "Great Bittern"=>"Botaurus stellaris",
 "Little Grebe"=>"Tachybaptus ruficollis",
 "Black-necked Grebe"=>"Podiceps nigricollis"
)
```

and what I have its a database result working with a `while()`.

I try something like this:

```
while(!$resrank->EOF){
    $array = array($resrank->fields["FIELD1"] => $resrank->fields["FIELD2"]);
    $resrank->MoveNext();
}
```

but obviously he creates alot of array's.

instead of that, i need array's like the example using `while()` or `foreach()`, dont know, any better way. How can i do this?

I'm not quite familiar with php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating individual arrays you need to populate the same one:

```
$items = array();
while(!$resrank->EOF){
    $items[$resrank->fields["FIELD1"]]  = $resrank->fields["FIELD2"];
    $resrank->MoveNext();
}
```

Good luck!